# Как использовать Stateless Session beans в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, ejb

У меня есть [проект на git](https://github.com/TupikovES/lab3-web-layer), который я написал в рамках прохождения лабораторных работ (лаба в которой описаны задачи, функционал и тех требования).

> **Краткое описание задачи**
>
> *Задача состоит в написании на Java Web-приложения для информационной
>   системы, работающей с базой данных через JDBC. Данные хранятся в базе
>   данных в нескольких таблицах. С помощью Web-приложения осуществляется
>   работа с данными: навигация, создание, модификация и удаление.*

Я решил использовал Spring. Задачу выполнил.

В следующей лабораторной такое задание:

> *Расширить функциональность написанного ранее приложения возможностью
>   описания объектов, хранящихся в базе данных, в виде XML документов.
>   Реализацию написать с использованием Session Beans. Структура XML
>   документа должна описываться с помощью DTD или XSD, которые строятся
>   на основании определенных в системе сущностей и их атрибутов.
>   Полученное описание объекта в виде XML нужно отображать в браузере в
>   виде HTML, полученное в результате трансформации XML c использованием
>   XSLT.*
>
> **Функции программы**
>
> *1. Для преобразования информации об объектах в XML нужно использовать
>   Stateless Session Beans.*
>
> 2. ...

Разбираясь, я конкретно ни чего не понял, только то, что `Stateless Session Beans` используются в EJB. Что это сессионный компонент и он не хранит состояние.

**Вопрос**

Как мне в Spring реализовать поставленную задачу используя Stateless Session Beans. Если надо делать с использованием EJB, то объясните, от и до как и что. Если есть альтернатива EJB в Spring, то расскажите про это, я так понимаю что она должна быть ведь Spring некая замена JavaEE. Просто я столько перебрал информации что уже в край запутался, и не понимаю с чего начинать и где заканчивать... Буду рад любой помощи в изучении данного вопроса!

Comment: Один из вариантов был создать новый сервис слой который будет работать с тем же Репозиторием (DAO) и преобразовывать полученный объект(DTO) в XML (используется EAV-модель БД), объявить реализацию сервиса как компонент со Scope session, но как объявить этот компонент Stateless'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас ввёл в заблуждение термин *session*. В рамках EJB это не сессия веб-приложении, это единичный сеанс связи клиента с сервисом. То есть, в терминологии web-приложения - *request*. Соответственно, для создания *session bean* в рамках Spring Web Application его нужно сделать со `scope = "request"`.

Помечать его как *stateless* не обязательно, ведь, согласно спецификации EJB,

> A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with the client.

То есть, главное, чтобы bean не сохранял никакие данные о клиенте между запросами. Это реализуется в Spring автоматически в рамках `scope = "request"`: на каждый запрос создаётся новый экземпляр бина*. Естественно, чтобы *bean* был по-настоящему *stateless*, нужно, чтобы он оперировал только его входными данными, то есть, не лез за данными в базу, сессию, другие *stateful* бины.

В рамках вашей задачи вам нужно просто создать сервис, который будет получать на вход объект и отдавать XML. Сам сервис не должен тянуть объект из базы, это за него должен делать другой сервис.

[Статья, описывающая session beans более подробно](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro002.htm#GIPJG)

Comment: То есть бин должен обращаться к DOA слою, который тащит объект из бд и отдает бину, тот в свою очередь отдает XML?

Comment: В рамках спринга этот бин не нужно объявлять как синглтон или это по умолчанию?